# Create an array from another and find the indices Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array with variables like `S`, `SV`, `V`, etc. I want to create a new array only with the `V` variable, so, for example:

```
V

SV

S

V
```

becomes

```
V

V
```

After this, I need to know the indices where each one of the `V` variables was found, in this case indices 1 and 4.

P.S  I already tried using an `if` in a `for` loop like this:

```
for i=1:744;
    if most_common_string{i} == 'V'
        periodo=most_common_string{i};
    end 
end
```

but I'm not getting an array with all the `V`'s. In fact I'm only getting a cell.

I also tried the `find` function to get the indices, but it is not working.

Comment: define "it is not working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second array for that; you can use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). Also, to compare strings use [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html), not `==` (that's probably why your code is not working):

```
>> array = {'V';'SV';'S';'V'};
>> ind = cellfun(@(s) strcmp(s,'V'), array)

ind =

     1
     0
     0
     1

>> find(ind)

ans =

     1
     4
```

Comment: Of course, anonymous functions. That's why I didn't get it to work with `cellfun`, I forgot to use an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to fix your `for` loop. The problem is, you're always assigning the value to the same variable. Not much to gain there. You need to add to an array:

```
result = {};
indices = [];
for i=1:numel(most_common_string)
    if most_common_string{i} == 'V'
        indices = [indices;i];
        result = [result;most_common_string(i)];
    end
end
```

Note that Code Analyzer might complain about your array changing sizes during loop iterations. You can't really avoid that since you don't kmow what size the array will have.

`find` probably doesn't work as you expect it to because it's not fit for use with cell arrays.